# linking php arrays together

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am trying to link php arrays together.

The values in dbTable array is:- rfq and quote

The values in dbColumns array is:- qid, item, price, id and item

The values in dbTData array is:- 1 ball, 200, 2 and bat.

Outputted as:-

```
  qid 1
  item ball
  price 200

  id 2
  item bat

  0 => quote
  1 => rfq
```

As shown the array dbColumns and dbTData is linking up, but how do i get dbTable to link with these please?

So the output would be:-

```
 quote
 qid 1
 item ball
 price 200

 rfq
 id 2
 item bat
```

The code so far is:-

```
    // form variables (arrays) passed over
$dbTData = $_POST["tupleData"];
$dbColumns = $_POST["column"];
$dbTable = $_POST["tableNames"];
$dbName = $_POST["dbName"];

// combining two arrays
$combineCT = array_combine($dbTData, $dbColumns);

// debugging echo database name
echo "The database in use = " . $dbName . "</br> ";

// database connection
$dbConnectionT = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbName);
if ($dbConnectionT ->connect_error){
    die ("database connection failed " . $dbConnection->connect_error);
}



//loop through associative array
foreach($combineCT as $message => $answer) 
            {
                echo $answer . " " . $message;
                echo "</br>";
            }

    echo "</br>";

foreach($dbTable as $key => $val)
        {
         echo "$key => $val\n";
            echo "</br>";
        }
```

Thanks in advance, I hope i have explained myself enough

Previous page:-

```
    $result = $dbConnectionT->query("SHOW TABLES");
                    echo "<form action='algone.php' method='POST'>";    
                while ( $row = $result->fetch_row() )
                {           


                    // printing out the table name  
                     echo '<h3>' . $row[0] . '</h3>';

                    // echo "here table ";
                    echo '' . "<input type='hidden' value='$dbName' name ='dbName' > "; 
                     echo '<th>' . "<input type='hidden' value='$row[0]' name ='tableNames[]' > "; 


                    $table = $row[0];   
                    $result1 = $dbConnectionT->query("SELECT * FROM $table");
                    if($result1) 
                    {

                                echo '<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" >';

                                $column = $dbConnectionT->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");
                                echo '<tr>';
                                while($row3 = $column->fetch_row() ) 
                                {

                                    echo '<th> ' . "<input type='hidden' value='$row3[0]' name ='column[]' > "; 
                                    echo ''.$row3[0]. " <input type ='text' name='tupleData[]'></th>" ;

                                    echo "</br>";

                                }
                                    echo '</tr>';

                                    while($row2 = $result1->fetch_row() ) 
                                {
                                  echo '<tr>';
                                  foreach($row2 as $key=>$value) {
                                    echo '<td>',$value . " here " .'</td>';
                                    echo "here row2 ";
                                  }
                                  echo '</tr>';
                                }
                                echo '</table><br />';

                    }




              }

             echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'> ";
                        echo "</form>";          

            $dbConnectionT->close();
```

New Code below **********************

```
    foreach ($AllData as $sigleData)
    {

        $table = $sigleData['name'];
        $columns = $sigleData['columns'];
        $columnData = $sigleData['data'];
        $combineCT = array_combine($columns , $columnData);

        foreach($combineCT as $colData => $tupleData) 
            {
                $tableS = implode(" ", $table);
                echo $tableS;
                echo "</br>";
                echo $colData. " " . $tupleData;
                echo "</br>";

                $sqlTuples = "INSERT INTO " . $tableS .  " (id, " . $colData . ") VALUES ('1', '" . $tupleData . "')";
                        if ($dbConnectionT->query($sqlTuples) == TRUE) 
                        {
                            echo "database updated";
                            echo "</br>";
                        }

            }
    }
```

Output

```
 quote
 qid 1
 quote
 item bin
 rfq
 id 3
 rfq
 item bat
```

Comment: This is all a bit like a riddle, I do not really understand what you are trying to do. Try this: instead of trying to explain the technical approach you use, modify your question such that you first state you goal from a user point of view. Without too much technical detail like database and tables and the like.

Comment: by combining  $combineCT  with  $dbTable at least according to the info you provided...

Comment: ok thanks, would you be able to give me an example please @JonidBendo please

Comment: // combining two arrays
$combineCT = array_combine($dbTData, $dbColumns);                 //combining other data                                                                                       $combineTotal = array_combine($dbTable , $combineCT );

Comment: Thanks, it says: -     Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements @JonidBendo

Comment: does $dbColumns  array always contain five items? I think i understand your question now.

Comment: It can contain 5, 6, 7, 8 or ten. it is dynamic on what it can hold. Thank you @JonidBendo

Comment: so on what basis do you want to separate them on tables? meaning i understand the way you use columns and data, but i see no clear way to separate them on tables.... No clear way to define which columns belong on which table.

Comment: So i want to loop through and the first table goes with the first set and the second table goes with the second data set @JonidBendo

Comment: yes but you have no dynamic way to define which are the columns that each table contains, this means that you need to do it manually, but then you will have problems with repeated columns (the ones that have the same name). The logic is at fault here and needs to be recreated.

Comment: thanks for the advice, i have attached the previous page code to see if you can help with that please and show where i am going wrong with the logic @JonidBendo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the form you should change `tableNames[]` (the name set the input) to `table[$i][name]`, afterwards changing the `column[]` to `table[$i][columns][]` and `tupleData[]` to `table[$i][data][]` suffices. you should add a `$i=0;` before executing the query and `$i++;` before closing the while cycle  `while ( $row = $result->fetch_row() ){}`

When you read them afterwards:

```
$AllData = $_POST["table"];

foreach ($AllData as $sigleData){

$table = $sigleData['name'];
$columns = $sigleData['columns'];
$columnData = $sigleData['data'];
$combineCT = array_combine($columns , $columnData );

}
```

And you can now use or echo the column and data of a table as well as the name. I think the general idea should be clear now.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help, Now i am getting an error for  "undefined index: name" && undefined index: columns" Although the data is ok.  Thank you very much again! @jonid Bendo

Comment: Did you change the input names on the previous page?

Comment: yes:-   table[$i][name][]  --- table[$i]columns[] -- table[$i][data][]

Comment: its should actually be table[$i][name] --- table[$i][columns][] and  table[$i][data][]  as i specifically wrote above.

Comment: you van var_dump($AllData); also to see the data that are actually passed and use the correct variables afterwards.

Comment: I am really sorry but it is still showing the same error  "undefined index: name" && undefined index: columns"      I was trying stuff myself when asking for help and I changed------   foreach ($AllData as $sigleData => $a){                ---------   Which removes the errors, Although I changed it back and now then errors are back :-( Sorry but thanks @Jonid Bendo

Comment: did you try to : var_dump($AllData); and see if all the data are there?

Comment: please try that and paste the output.

Comment: By the looks of it all the data is not there, just the $columnData, hence why there are no errors from that array. thats a nice debugging trick, thanks

Comment: array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'data' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '200' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'data' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'bagg' (length=4)

Comment: I think it is working now, but when i try to echo it out it says --- Array to string conversion ERROR. How do i echo the values out please

Comment: array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'quote' (length=5)
      'columns' => string 'price' (length=5)
      'data' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '3' (length=1)
          1 => string 'bat' (length=3)
          2 => string '200' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'rfq' (length=3)
      'columns' => string 'item' (length=4)
      'data' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '2' (length=1)
          1 => string 'bagg' (length=4)

Comment: now everything should be fine, its the naming that you should be careful of. As the data are exactly what they are expected to be.

Comment: There are multiple "columns" although only the last one is coming out, Do i have to do the same as the table and make a counter table[$i]columns[$j]    to retrive all the columns please? Thanks @Jonid Bendo

Comment: This means the name of yhe input is incorrect and missing a [] please check that  it has [] on the end as i wrote you on my amswer

Comment: thank you, I am trying to insert the data into the tables and columns now, I have added the code above to show you where I am.. Do i have to do a while loop over the code, until nothing is left somewhere? please

Comment: Here is a sample code that should normally work directly, normally you should also filter the data otherwise you are seeing some sql injection vulnerabilities: http://pastebin.com/3vn1prsX

Comment: this is not going live, so i am not worried about sql injection. Thank you for the point though! I am getting an error "Array to String conversion"   from the insert statement $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (".$columns.") VALUES(".$columnData.")";     ----  it is because of the $table array... ---  $table = $sigleData['name'];     do i have to do anything to this line please? thanks

Comment: it should be a string with the guidelines i provided and not an array... even the var_dump you provided shows that it should be a name. So please make sure the info i provided are followed correctly.

Comment: Something is not working as expected with the insert statement, it is to do with the $columns array, When i do ----------      $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO " . $table .  " (id) VALUES ('" . $columnData . "')";    ---------- The insert works (although adds all data into id), but when i do --------------       $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO rfq ( " . $columns . ") VALUES( '" . $columnData . "')";   The insert does not work, thanks

Comment: var_dump the query so you see where it fails, please understand i can not help you like this since this goes out of the scope of StackOverflow. Hope that you can understand me.